# How to load appended data using pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

I am working with a large set of data, and hence, cannot rely on the RAM of my computer to store a list.  I would like to store calculated elements onto a file on disk as opposed to a list (I am using the `pickle` package).  A simplified version of my code is below:

```
import pickle 

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# I am separately using each element in list 'a' in a calculation, and
# then appending it to test.p
for item in a:
    # Do calculation (simple calculation shown for question)
    new_item = item*2
    pickle.dump(new_item, open("test.p", "ab"))

b = pickle.load(open("test.p", "rb"))
print(b)
```

However, `print(b)` only display the first element `2`. How would I load all of the elements that are stored on `test.p`?

Comment: You should use the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) module for this